# Setup distributed arangodb cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, distributed, arangodb

I whould like to setup an arangodb cluster with 3 virtual machines.

1. In the first machine I executed `$ arangodb` I got the following output

   ```
   ubuntu@arangodb-1:/etc/arangodb3$ arangodb

   2018/04/19 09:15:46 Starting arangodb version 0.10.4, build 553aab6

   2018/04/19 09:15:46 Serving as master with ID '5f388575' on :8528...

   2018/04/19 09:15:46 Waiting for 3 servers to show up.

   2018/04/19 09:15:46 Use the following commands to start other servers:

   arangodb --starter.data-dir=./db2 --starter.join 127.0.0.1

   arangodb --starter.data-dir=./db3 --starter.join 127.0.0.1

   2018/04/19 09:15:46 Listening on 0.0.0.0:8528 (:8528)
   ```
2. In the second machine i got the following problem

   ```
   ubuntu@arangodb-2:~$ arangodb --starter.data-dir=./db2 --starter.join 10.100.0.105

   2018/04/19 09:23:12 Starting arangodb version 0.10.4, build 553aab6

   2018/04/19 09:23:12 Contacting master http://10.100.0.105:8528...

   2018/04/19 09:23:27 Cannot start because of error from master: Post 
   http://10.100.0.105:8528/hello: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

   2018/04/19 09:23:28 Contacting master http://10.100.0.105:8528...
   ```

Can some one help me to getting started with arangodb cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently your machines do not seem to reach each other. `ifconfig` on all three machines should indicate which network they share.

1. Make sure that they can ping each other.
2. make sure that you can run `curl <other-machine>:8528/version` to respond something like `{"version":"0.10.4","build":"553aab6"}` or so.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the `--starter.address=addr` option as described on https://github.com/arangodb-helper/arangodb/blob/master/docs/Manual/Programs/Starter/Options.md